# What happens when there are no await after create_task

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am trying to understand asyncio and I am quite confused about tasks.
Specifically, I know a task will run when the current coroutine is suspended and controll is passed to the event loop. What if await is never called after a task is created, and the coroutine just exit?

For example

```
import asyncio

async def print_stuff(s):
    print(s)

async def print_wrapper(s):
    print(f"{s}: create task")
    asyncio.create_task(print_stuff(s))
    print(f"{s}: sleeping")
    print(f"{s}: ending coroutine")

async def sleep_wrapper(s):
    print(f"{s}: before sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print(f"{s}: after sleep")

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(print_stuff("stuff"))
    asyncio.create_task(print_wrapper("wrapper"))
    asyncio.create_task(sleep_wrapper("abc"))

asyncio.run(main())
print("after main")
```

The output is

```
stuff
wrapper: create task
wrapper: sleeping
wrapper: ending coroutine
abc: before sleep
after main
```

What I don't understand is

1. why would I see any output from the tasks at all, after main ends, shouldn't the event loop ends with it?
2. why "wrapper" and "abc: after sleep" were not printed while the other messages were?

Comment: You don't `await` a single task in `main`?

Answer (score 1):

I briefly looked at the `asyncio` source and I think the event loop makes one loop (or maybe two?) iterations and then it returns, because the stop condition (finished `main`) is true.

There are 4 tasks at the beginning, 3 created in the `main` and the 4th is the `main` coroutine itself. In one loop iteration each task that is ready is run one "step", i.e. new tasks from the beginning, other tasks from the point where the previous step finished. A "step" always finishes at the point where the task cannot continue and that is either the end of the corresponding coroutine (a `return` or after the last instruction or an exception) or at an `await` that cannot immediately return a value. In the first case, the task becomes "done". In the latter case the task becomes not ready and waits for some pending `future` value. When the future becomes "done", the associated task can be scheduled to run again. In your code it is the sleep where the "step" ends.